# How to change backup location dynamically in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Requirement : 
Due to some space issue our scheduled jobs are failing so to avoid this I have developed if FreeSpace is >50 GB then backup to F drive , If FreeSpace is < 50 then backup to G drive .. it has to check the all the drives and change the path automatically. Some how the below code is not working.Help on this highly appriciated.

```
create table #Space(Drive varchar(4),SpaceAvailable varchar(15))
insert into #Space(Drive,SpaceAvailable)
exec xp_fixeddrives 

Alter table #Space add FinalSpace as spaceavailable/1024
select * from #Space

Declare @FreeSpace varchar(10)
select @FreeSpace=(select top 1 FinalSpace  from #Space)
print @FreeSpace
if (@FreeSpace <50)
begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='G:\PerfDB.bak'
end
if (@FreeSpace >50 )
begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='F:\PerfDB.bak'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven for your reply.Its not like I am not voting or responding.Some how I am not able to either accept answer or vote.

Comment: Fair enough. No idea why you can't accept or vote but I've removed my comment.

Comment: What specific errors are you receiving when you run your code?

Comment: Hi Gray, Thanks for quick reply. It is not entering into if condition and displaying just commands executed successfully.

Comment: Comment out the backup commands.  Add a print command such as "Backup to G:" inside your "if" blocks.  Works for me.  If you run more than once, you will need to explicitly drop the temp table.  Check for results in the messages tab in Management Studio.

Comment: Gray - The below code is not entering into loop Declare @FreeSpace int=5
select @FreeSpace=(select top 1 FinalSpace  from #Space)
if (@FreeSpace<50)
begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='c:\PerfDB.bak'
Print 'Loop Entered'
end
else
begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='F:\PerfDB.bak'
Print 'Loop Entered'
end

Comment: I have tried with Print command but its not entering into loop.

Comment: if (@FreeSpace between 0 and 50) begin  print 'No Space Available'
end if (@FreeSpace between 50 and 124  )
begin  backup database PerfDB to disk='E:\PerfDB.bak'
Print 'Loop Entered to E' end
if (@FreeSpace  between 125 and 150  )
begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='F:\PerfDB.bak'
Print 'Loop Entered to F'
end
The above code is entering into 2 conditions i.e if freespace is 50 then its entering into e drive as well as no space available.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
create table #Space(Drive varchar(4),SpaceAvailable varchar(15))
insert into #Space(Drive,SpaceAvailable)
exec xp_fixeddrives 

Alter table #Space add FinalSpace as spaceavailable/1024
select * from #Space

Declare @FreeSpace int=0
select @FreeSpace=51 --(select top 1 FinalSpace  from #Space)
print @FreeSpace
if (@FreeSpace between 0 and 50)
begin
print 'No Space Available'
end
if (@FreeSpace between 51 and 124  )

begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='E:\PerfDB.bak'
Print 'Loop Entered to E'
end
if (@FreeSpace  between 125 and 150  )
begin

backup database PerfDB to disk='F:\PerfDB.bak'
Print 'Loop Entered to F'
end
```

Comment: Dear  Lieven Keersmaekers , I knew kind of you guys doesn't even know the answer so please do not post such comments again for any one that will be great help from your end to this forum folks.

Comment: In the above code how can I change the drive name dynamically i.e if >50 GB free space then it has to move E drive until <50 GB free space. If E drive also fills upto 50 GB free space then it has to go to the next drive that can be G or F or H except C drive.