# Dynamically change Drive location based on free space?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If E drive free space is below 50 GB then it has to move G Drive. Again if E and G drive free space is <=50 GB then it has to next available drives. 
Condition : Drive names are not fixed and backup should never go to C drive.

create table #Space(Drive varchar(4),SpaceAvailable varchar(15))
    insert into #Space(Drive,SpaceAvailable)
    exec xp_fixeddrives

```
Alter table #Space add FinalSpace as spaceavailable/1024
select * from #Space

Declare @FreeSpace int=0
select @FreeSpace=(select top 1 FinalSpace  from #Space)
print @FreeSpace
if (@FreeSpace between 0 and 50)
begin
print 'No Space Available'
end
if (@FreeSpace between 51 and 124  )

begin
backup database PerfDB to disk='E:\PerfDB.bak' -- Here E drive should change to G OR F OR H drives 
Print 'Loop Entered to E'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change backup location dynamically in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133121/how-to-change-backup-location-dynamically-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi MistetrPositive thanks for your reply. I only posted the link which you shared hence there was problem in code for dynamic drive letters .e If E drive free space is below 50 GB then it has to move G Drive. Again if E and G drive free space is <=50 GB then it has to next available drives. Condition : Drive names are not fixed and backup should never go to C drive.